# Capture view with custom UIView in storyboard returning nothing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, electronic-signature

I am using this signature class to add signatures to my iOS application: https://github.com/jharwig/SignatureDemo/blob/master/SignatureDemo/NICSignatureView.h

I have the signature view in a storyboard form sheet, and I am able to draw and everything and it works....

However, I want to save the signature as an image.  To do that, I am doing this:

```
UIView *view = self.view;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

The image, however, is all white, without the signature.  I assume that is becuase the view is not add programmatically, but with a storyboard.  However, the `addSubview` is not adding the view.

The signature class also has a built in method to return a UIImage, but I am unsure how to call this from a view controller that has the view set in a storyboard.

So my question is, how can I get the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this property to your view controller

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView* mySigView;
```

Connect mySigView property with your UIView (NICSignatureView) in storyboard

Trigger the following action in your view controller after you hit a save button:

```
NICSignatureView* sig = (NICSignatureView *)self.mySigView;
UIImage* myimage = [sig signatureImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myimage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Do not forget to import NICSignatureView.h in your view controller

```
#import "NICSignatureView.h"
```

You can now find the signature in your camera roll

Comment: Wow.  How did I not think of this?  Thank you, kind sir!